# Automatically re-sort rows and update the values of a sort column

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table with an auto-incremented index, but also a "sortorder" field that controls the, well, sort order, when data is queried and displayed.

E.g.

```
id    title     sortorder
1     this      10
2     that      30
3     other     20
4     something 25
```

So far, so good. I'd like to create a function to automatically re-order these though - well, not re-order, but redo the values of the sortorder column per the existing order. The desired outcome from the above after running the function would be this:

```
id    title     sortorder
1     this      10
2     that      40
3     other     20
4     something 30
```

Is this something that can be done with an SQL statement in MariaDB (I have not found anything for that yet), or do I need to do it in my (php) application?

The logic for the new sort order values is based on the ordering by the sortorder column.

The reason for renumbering is that the sort order values are going to be manually maintained in the application, but it may be occasionally helpful to start with a clean slate. Users will be trained to "leave some room" in the values to allow for future edits.

On day one, "sortorder" will get (manually) populated with, say, 10, 20, 30, etc. Or possibly 100, 200, 300, etc. So that if they need to reorder things in the future, this will allow changing one item's sortorder value to say 25, to put it *between* the items with 20 and 30. Make sense?

But eventually, it's possible that the users could paint themselves into a corner, or at any rate make things confusing for themselves. It would be nice to build them a button that simply goes through the rows, and re-sets all the sortorder values, to preserve the existing row order but to make the values of sortorder be spaced evenly by intervals anew.

Comment: Just update the sortorder of id=2 and id=4 by update queries

Comment: What is the logic behind the new sort order values?

Comment: This is called "renumbering". In this case, the step is 10. An `UPDATE` with `ROW_NUMBER()` should do the trick.

Comment: @nice_dev thanks for asking, I updated the question now to explain the logic and reasoning

Comment: @KenLee yes, I could do that in the application. My question is whether there is a way to do it in the SQL instead.

Comment: So, users will assign the sortorder manually? Correct? Also, why will sortorder with value 35 come between 20 and 30?

Comment: @TheImpaler that sounds intriguing, but I'm not seeing how to implement it, or even how to begin implementing it

Comment: @nice_dev, I believe the OP want to assign the sortorder by a "SQL query" so that the order will be separated by 10 for each subsequent record.

Comment: @nice_dev yes, the users will *normally* assign sortorder values manually. Sorry, the 35 was a typo, 25 will come between 20 and 30, not 35. I want to create an occasional function that would automatically renumber the sortorder column

Comment: _it's possible that the users could paint themselves into a corner, or at any rate make things confusing_ I think you are way ahead of them on that

Comment: @RiggsFolly ha ha, thanks!  Seriously though, it's pretty common to have a sorting column. I could envision wanting to do this even if there was a drag and drop interface to reorder items in the application. We know what order we want them in, how best to redo the sortoder column values? That is the question.

Comment: Yup, I could not help myself! Sorry. I understand the concept well enough, I just dont see any LOGIC in the order you suggest should be achieved by this Automatic reorder process, Without a bit of logic in creating that default order, i have to revert to my previous comment

Comment: @KenLee It still seems confusing to me.

Comment: @GHolmes Ok, so when you say "redo the sortorder column" values, it looks like simple DB updates. When you show this on the UI, do you show them in a sorted ascending manner?

Comment: Do you want to do this in only SQL or with SQL and PHP

Comment: @nice_dev if by "simple DB updates" you mean I should reassign the values in the application, sure, I could do that. I could query the table, sort by the sortorder column, iterate over the results, and update each record with an incremented/stepped value. Sure. But I was wondering if there is a way to do it in SQL instead for better performance though.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please see my response to nice_dev. I'd prefer to do it in SQL since I think it would perform better. Seems like there should be a way, but maybe there isn't.

Comment: Did you read @TheImpaler comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, but I am not finding any examples how to implement that.

Comment: @GHolmes Maybe I get it now, thanks.

Comment: Edited to make it clear you are using MariaDB. MariaDB is not fully compatible with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MariaDB you can do:

```
update t
join (
  select id, 10 * row_number() over (order by sortorder) as rn10
  from t
) x on x.id = t.id
set t.sortorder = x.rn10;
```

Result:

```
 id  title      sortorder 
 --- ---------- --------- 
 1   this       10        
 2   that       40        
 3   other      20        
 4   something  30
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=2da6e4a4b0a43b57dd2066124536232d).

Comment: That works and is cleaner than the other answer; thanks!

Comment: And it works in both MySQL and MariaDB (at least according to the fiddle).

Answer (score 2):

Update: This solution works in MySQL 8.0, but not in MariaDB, because MariaDB's support for CTE doesn't support UPDATE statements. I'll leave this solution here for readers who use MySQL, but it doesn't work for MariaDB.

```
mysql> select * from NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions;
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | title     | sortorder |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | this      |        10 |
|  2 | that      |        30 |
|  3 | other     |        20 |
|  4 | something |        25 |
+----+-----------+-----------+

mysql> with cte as (
    select id, row_number() over (order by sortorder) * 10 as new_sortorder 
    from NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions
  ) 
  update NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions join cte using (id) 
  set sortorder = new_sortorder;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions;
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | title     | sortorder |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | this      |        10 |
|  2 | that      |        40 |
|  3 | other     |        20 |
|  4 | something |        30 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try to execute that in phpmyadmin I get

Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "with" at position 0)
SQL query: Documentation

with cte as ( select id, row_number() over (order by sortorder) * 10 as new_sortorder from NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions ) update NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions join cte using (id) set sortorder = new_sortorder

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right synt

Comment: The error message indicates you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. And you must be using MariaDB older than version 10.2, when the CTE syntax was introduced (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/).

Comment: Hmm, using Server version: 10.2.41-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: Doesn't work on command line either. 

MariaDB [(none)]> with cte as (    select id, row_number() over (order by sortorder) * 10 as new_sortorder     from NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions )   update NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions join cte using (id)   set sortorder = new_sortorder;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'update NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions join cte using (id)   set sortorder = new_sorto...' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]>

Comment: Ah - MariaDB supports CTE syntax, but not if you use UPDATE after defining the CTE. Only SELECT. This is an incompatibility in the implementation between MariaDB and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

This would require some subqueries to be written inside. Steps of what I did are as follows:

- Table name I used is `tt`. You need to change it according to your table name.
- First is to get all rows in sorted order of `sortorder` column.
- Second, declare a variable, say `@serial_no` and keep incrementing it by `1` on every selected row. This is an old school technique but I find it more readable.
- Assign new `sortorder` values in this new parent select query. For now, I have just multiplied it's serial number(as in rank) by 10. You can adjust accordingly.
- In your update query, inner join current copy of the table being updated with this select query and update the new `sortorder` column values correctly by matching them on `id` column.

**Snippet:**

```
update tt A 
inner join (
    select id, title, (@serial_no := @serial_no + 1) as serial_no,@serial_no * 10 as `sortorder`
    from (
        select *
        from tt
        order by sortorder asc
    ) temp_derived,(SELECT @serial_no := 0) as sn    
) B
on A.id = B.id
set A.sortorder = B.sortorder
```

**Update:**

I just realised the control is completely shifted from user to DB. If you wish to update multiple rows with their new sortorder values, I wish to propose a workaround technique since I have never seen updating multiple rows with new values submitted from user in bulk(happy to learn if there exists one).

- You need to map old values with new values, say in an associative array in PHP.
- Start a DB transaction in MySQL.
- Insert all new rows in bulk.
- Delete all previous old rows in one go with IDs sent from PHP (in a prepared statement preferably with the previously mapped assoc array)
- Commit the transaction.
- Rollback ofcourse if something goes wrong.

Comment: That ... may have worked!  I need to do some more testing, I will return to this tomorrow and likely mark as the answer!

Comment: That works but the other answer from the Impaler was cleaner. Thank you though!

Comment: No issues. I am glad I could be of help.